# Anyone know how to create CSS rectangle with one corner chopped off?

Tags: css

Does anyone know how to create a css polygon that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I used pseudo classes (before and after) but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: show us what you tried, we may explain why it didn't work and how it could :) is it a plain white background or is it a complex background that is suppose to show around and down that corner ?

Comment: You can try a solution based on this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mdQzH/

Comment: or more complexe , chop off some parts and still show background behind :) http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/yJfjl , the solution is the one that fits to your need.

Comment: It's for div that will sit above an image in a slider - I'll post an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6S6N/1/) that may be helpful. I adapted it from this one: http://jsfiddle.net/76EUw/2/

Anyway, here's what I did:

```
.corner {
    width: calc(300px - 20px); /*300 is the width, 20 is the size of the 'cut'*/
    height: 0px;
    /*change the top/left depending on which corner you want to use*/
    border-top: 20px solid red; /*I made this red just so it was easier to see*/
    border-right: 20px solid white; /*not sure what you will do if this is not on a white background.*/
}
.main {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the pseudo-class **:after**

This makes for a cleaner DOM.

http://jsfiddle.net/9Wyuj/2/

```
/* Rectangle with bottom right (br) corner chopped */

.rectangle-br-chopped {
   width: 300px; 
   height: 100px; 
   background: blue;
}
.rectangle-br-chopped:after {
   height: 0;
   width: 240px;
   content:"";
   position: absolute; 
   border-top: 30px solid blue; 
   border-left: 30px solid blue;  
   border-right: 30px solid white; 
   margin: 100px 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

oki, let's go with the pseudo technic of mine which doesnt hide main background :)
http://jsfiddle.net/XE4GE/

```
p {margin:1em auto;
    width:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    color:white;
    font-size:2em;
    padding:1em;
}
p:after {
    content:'';
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    margin:-30px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
        transform:rotate(45deg);
    outline:1000px solid black;
}
body {
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/10);
}
```